# How to update sub-sub-documents in spring-boot mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

```
{ 
    "refNum" : "ESMEUS", 
    "faqs" : [
        {
            "type" : "about company", 
            "answer" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            "questions" : [
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "about ceo", 
            "answer" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            "questions" : [
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "about salary", 
            "answer" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            "questions" : [
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "awards", 
            "answer" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            "questions" : [
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }, 
                {
                    "question" : "tell me abt company"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to add a new question for the "type":"about company"
I need a query for this in spring boot MongoDB.

Comment: Why not just load the document, update the POJO and just `save`?

Comment: @Strelok could u please provide me the code for solving the above problem. collection name: "faq" and JSON format is above mentioned.